# Update webview page number when updating font

Tags: ios, swift, webview, epub

I'm working on a book reader iOS application and using webview for displaying epub books. The 3rd party library I'm using for parsing epub book is "KFEpubKit".

I've to give option to user to adjust the font size (as in iBooks), and I've achieved that feature by updating the font of webview as:

```
let textSizeRule = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '\(fontPercentage)%'"
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(textSizeRule)
```

The problem I'm facing is that by increasing/decreasing font size, page number of book must also change. But I'm unable to do so.

How can I achieve this functionality in the way other book reading applications are doing it (i.e. kindle, iBook etc)?

Comment: For time being, i'm reloading the book and computing page number. Although user experience is not that good but i didn't find any other solution

Comment: I have written a ePub reader in swift that handle this take a look https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second WebView object which is hidden. You do the same thing ("For time being, i'm reloading the book and computing page number.") in the background webview.
In your webViewDidFinishLoad method, check which webview is loaded

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    if webView == backgroundWebview {
        //Compute number of pages

    } else {
        //Foreground webview

    }
}
```

So the user is not disturbed by a reloading webview.

Hope this helps!